# Correct answer at rustlings course, but not happy with it

Tags: string, rust, hashmap

This is complaining on highest of niveaus, but I solved a task from the rustlings course and I'm confident that this can't be the optimal solution - or even a good one.

The task: https://github.com/rust-lang/rustlings/blob/main/exercises/hashmaps/hashmaps3.rs

My solution (only the the relevant bit):

```
fn build_scores_table(results: String) -> HashMap<String, Team> {
    // The name of the team is the key and its associated struct is the value.
    let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();

    for r in results.lines() {
        let v: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_1_name = v[0].to_string();
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        let team_2_name = v[1].to_string();
        let team_2_score: u8 = v[3].parse().unwrap();

        let team_1 = scores.entry(team_1_name.clone()).or_insert(Team {
            name: team_1_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        });
        team_1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
        team_1.goals_conceded += team_2_score;

        let team_2 = scores.entry(team_2_name.clone()).or_insert(Team {
            name: team_2_name.clone(),
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        });
        team_2.goals_scored += team_2_score;
        team_2.goals_conceded += team_1_score;
    }
    scores
}
```

My problem is, that I'm cloning the strings (twice!) inside the `.entry()` method an also in the Team struct. I tried using it without, but it's not working (borrowing stuff) and using the `&` but it's not happy because it expects `String` - not `&String`.

Comment: I had the exact same thought while working on this exact same problem

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Not sure what's not working exactly? You can just move on the second use site, it works fine:

```rust
        let team_1 = scores.entry(team_1_name.clone()).or_insert(Team {
            name: team_1_name,
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        });
        team_1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
        team_1.goals_conceded += team_2_score;
```

If you want zero cloning in the success case (where there's already an entry for the team) the code is a little less sexy but it also compiles fine:

```rust
        if let Some(t) = scores.get_mut(&team_1_name) {
            t.goals_scored += team_1_score;
            t.goals_conceded += team_2_score;
        } else {
            scores.insert(team_1_name.clone(), Team {
                name: team_1_name,
                goals_scored: team_1_score,
                goals_conceded: team_2_score,
            });
        }
```

Technically we can even remove the initial `to_string` and do no allocation in the hit case (obviously that means two allocations in the no-hit case):

```rust
        let team_1_name = v[0];
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        // ...
        if let Some(t) = scores.get_mut(team_1_name) {
            t.goals_scored += team_1_score;
            t.goals_conceded += team_2_score;
        } else {
            scores.insert(team_1_name.to_string(), Team {
                name: team_1_name.to_string(),
                goals_scored: team_1_score,
                goals_conceded: team_2_score,
            });
        }
```

Alternatively, remove the `name` from the `Team` struct, it's not really valuable since you have the hashmap key. Though at this point you don't have a `Team` struct anymore so it should probably be renamed e.g. `Score` or `Goals` (and you can strip the prefix from the two members left).

Answer (score 2):

You don't need the second `.clone()` calls (in the `Team`), because you can allow the struct to take ownership of that one, as nothing else uses it afterwards. They set the hashmap up kinda weird for you, since the key and the value both contain the team name. If you just remove it from the struct definition, there isn't any more need for cloning (it is never used, anyways).

```rust
struct Team {
    goals_scored: u8,
    goals_conceded: u8,
}

fn build_scores_table(results: String) -> HashMap<String, Team> {
    // The name of the team is the key and its associated struct is the value.
    let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();

    for r in results.lines() {
        let v: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_1_name = v[0].to_string();
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        let team_2_name = v[1].to_string();
        let team_2_score: u8 = v[3].parse().unwrap();

        let team_1 = scores.entry(team_1_name).or_insert(Team {
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        });
        team_1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
        team_1.goals_conceded += team_2_score;

        let team_2 = scores.entry(team_2_name).or_insert(Team {
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        });
        team_2.goals_scored += team_2_score;
        team_2.goals_conceded += team_1_score;
    }
    scores
}
```

Comment: It is not uncommon to have the identifier (team name in this case) of a data structure be used as the key and also be stored in the data structure itself. So, they did **not** set up the hashmap weirdly.

Comment: [main]let team_1 = scores.entry(team_1_name.clone()).or_insert(Team {
            name: team_1_name,
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        });
        team_1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
        team_1.goals_conceded += team_2_score;

        let team_2 = scores.entry(team_2_name.clone()).or_insert(Team {
            name: team_2_name,
            goals_scored: 0,
            goals_conceded: 0,
        });
        team_2.goals_scored += team_2_score;
        team_2.goals_conceded += team_1_score;[main]

Answer (score 1):

This is ultimately what I ended up with, not crazy about having to use "and_modify" twice, but c'est la vie.

```
fn build_scores_table(results: String) -> HashMap<String, Team> {
    let mut scores: HashMap<String, Team> = HashMap::new();

    for r in results.lines() {
        let v: Vec<&str> = r.split(',').collect();
        let team_1_name = v[0].to_string();
        let team_1_score: u8 = v[2].parse().unwrap();
        let team_2_name = v[1].to_string();
        let team_2_score: u8 = v[3].parse().unwrap();
        scores.entry(team_1_name.clone())
            .and_modify(|a| a.goals_scored += team_1_score)
            .and_modify(|b| b.goals_conceded += team_2_score)
            .or_insert(Team { name: team_1_name,
                goals_scored: team_1_score,
                goals_conceded: team_2_score });
        scores.entry(team_2_name.clone())
            .and_modify(|a| a.goals_scored += team_2_score)
            .and_modify(|b| b.goals_conceded += team_1_score)
            .or_insert(Team { name: team_2_name,
                goals_scored: team_2_score,
                goals_conceded: team_1_score });
    }
    scores
}
```

Comment: Couldn't you combine the `and_modify` steps by using a block inside the closure?

Comment: You're absolutely right that you can! Basically 
```.and_modify(|t| {t.goals_scored += team_2_score; t.goals_conceded += team_1_score })```

Answer (score 1):

I have this one. (in reference to why you need not dereference to update)

TLDR is, in rust, composite types (vecs, structs, enums...) use the Deref trait, which will dereference under the hood for you, when you are doing something that moves into a field, is an index, or is a method call on the reference to a composite type.

longer form:

`team_1` is a variable. You are essentially binding a method (.insert specifically) that returns a mutable reference (&mut value) that is then saved to that variable.

the value in this case is not just a primitive type like an integer, but a composite type (a struct).
later, you are calling a field in that struct via the variable that is a mutable reference to the struct. This is when the Deref trait of a struct kicks in and will automatically `*team_1` for you.
The proof is when you try and type out `*team_1.goals_scored` with no `()`. Rust looks at `team_1.goals_scored` which is already derefed to a u8 type, and sees you are asking `*u8` which isn't a thing. `(*team_1).goals_scored` works because you are explicitly doing `*&mut value`, however, because of the Deref trait on the thing behind this mutable reference, this isn't necessary.

maybe another question pops up like, "well if they already have a Deref trait that could be implemented to types, why not do it for primitive types as well?"
There are a couple reasons that come up....but honestly the only one I can understand is, people that have used rust are used to needing to explicitly deref primitive types, so changing that will annoy the community as well as break current use if updated....
Another one is the potential cost of adding this abstraction to every instance of manipulating primitive types which I assume could maybe add up to allot?
The last one is "it could add unknown complexity"....which I have yet to think of a time this would happen, other than going from one way of things to a new way of things...

Answer (score 0):

Learnt something! Thank you!

BTW, I have a follow up question: In contrast to the [Rust book](https://rust-book.cs.brown.edu/ch08-03-hash-maps.html), why can't we add (*) to this line

```
team_1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
```

to become

```
*team_1.goals_scored += team_1_score;
```

Any reason it fails?

I think it is somewhat related to the fact that is a type `Team` instead of primitive type as value of hashmap, but I still wish have a clear understanding about that.

Comment: If you have a new question, please ask it by clicking the [Ask Question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/ask) button. Include a link to this question if it helps provide context. - [From Review](/review/late-answers/33601704)

Answer (score 0):

In regards to the follow up question, have you tried the following:

```
(*team_1).goals_scored += team_1_score;
```